# Is it possible to wrap looping PHP output in tags?

Tags: php, loops, styling

everyone. I'm having a bit of a PHP conundrum here and I couldn't find a good answer that already existed. You see, I'm working on a project where I have to take a classmate's discography website and revamp it with PHP, to where, instead of having the album covers and tracklists hard-coded in, it would query the database for them. My problem is that I have to keep the general style of his site intact, and I'm having trouble doing that. Basically his styles depend on having the album cover, name, and tracklists in div tags, and the style he's got in place is achieved through both Bootstrap and his own, custom CSS stylesheet.

Before I start to ramble, my question is: is there any way to wrap looping output in HTML tags? I need to get the album cover, album name, and tracklists in a div tag, but only the tracklists loop. Here is the code I have in place to query the database:

```
<?php
require ('mysqli_connect.php');

// Connect to database server

mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "instructor") or die(mysql_error());

// Select database

mysql_select_db("phprediscography") or die(mysql_error());

// SQL query

$q = "SELECT DISTINCT albums.albumname, albums.albumID, albums.coverart
    FROM albums
    JOIN tracks
    ON albums.albumID=tracks.albumID"; //select UNIQUE results from database
$t = "SELECT trackname FROM tracks WHERE albumID = 1";
$b = "SELECT trackname FROM tracks WHERE albumID = 2";
$n = "SELECT trackname FROM tracks WHERE albumID = 3";
$r = "SELECT trackname FROM tracks WHERE albumID = 4";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $q);
$result1 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $t);
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $b);
$result3 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $n);
$result4 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $r);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { //loop through database to get each album
    echo '<img class="img-responsive" src=' . $row['coverart'] . '>' . '<br />';
    echo '<h2>' . $row['albumname'] . "</h2><br />";
    if ($row['albumID'] == 1) {
        foreach($result1 as $row1) { //loop through tracks and output to page
            echo '<p>' . $row1['trackname'] . '</p>';
        }
    }

    if ($row['albumID'] == 2) {
        foreach($result2 as $row2) { //loop through tracks and output to page
            echo '<p>' . $row2['trackname'] . '</p>';
        }
    }

    if ($row['albumID'] == 3) {
        foreach($result3 as $row3) { //loop through tracks and output to page
            echo '<p>' . $row3['trackname'] . '</p>';
        }
    }

    if ($row['albumID'] == 4) {
        foreach($result4 as $row4) { //loop through tracks and output to page
            echo '<p>' . $row4['trackname'] . '</p>';
        }
    }
}

// Close the database connection

mysql_close();
?>
```

If I need to post anything else, let me know, this is my first-ever question so I'm just kind of feeling it out.

Comment: `mysql_connect()`/`mysql_select_db()` does not mix with `mysqli_query()`/`mysqli_fetch_array()`. I assume those `mysql_connect()`/`mysql_select_db()` are old code lines that should be deleted, as you have `require('mysqli_connect.php');`?

Comment: Does your code working fine? Then I will provide you solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing your `$t = "SELECT trackname FROM tracks WHERE albumID = #";` and `if($row['albumID']==#)` you are essentially still hardcoding similar to your friend. Just do 1 query, where you join all the tracks. Then when looping, group by the `albumname` -

```
<?php
require('mysqli_connect.php');

// SQL query
$q = "SELECT albums.albumname, albums.albumID, albums.coverart, tracks.trackname
FROM albums
JOIN tracks
ON albums.albumID=tracks.albumID";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $q);

$current_albumID = ""; //create current albumID var to be used below.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){//loop through database to get each album

   if($row['albumID'] != $current_albumID){
       echo '<img class="img-responsive" src='.$row['coverart'] . '>' . '<br />';
       echo '<h2>' . $row['albumname'] . "</h2><br />";
       $current_albumID = $row['albumID']; // set current albumID to this albumID
   }
   echo '<p>' . $row['trackname'] . '</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I think I'm going to go with this for for now -- it still breaks the page because the CSS is absurd, but it at least works better. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out, this worked perfectly! Thank you so much, this has been giving me problems for weeks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead: Get all the data you're after in your first query, then use php to process that into your output:

```
$q = "SELECT albums.albumname, albums.albumID, albums.coverart, tracks.trackname
FROM albums
JOIN tracks ON albums.albumID=tracks.albumID";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $q);

$lastAlbumId = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if ($lastAlbumId != $row['albumID']) {
           echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.htmlentities($row['coverart']).'"><br />';
           echo '<h2>'.htmlentities($row['albumname']).'</h2><br />';
    }
    echo '<p>'.htmlentities($trackname).'</p>';
    $lastAlbumId = $row['albumID'];
}
```

A few things to note:

1. I added use of `htmlentities` to escape the user data so malicious people can't type in HTML somewhere and have it appear on your site. This is something you should do almost everywhere you're displaying data from a database in a html site, except for very rare cases where you know what you're doing.
2. You probably don't need those `<br />` tags - `<h2>` is a block level element so it'll force itself onto it's own line anyway (unless there's some silly CSS rules somewhere).

Also note - the above code is untested - typed straight into browser. There may be some syntax errors - let me know if you see any problem and I'll happily edit the answer. (or you can suggest an edit).

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\phprevamp\get2.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phprevamp\get2.php on line 10

It throws me these errors when I load it...

Comment: @JetlagMadman Ah right - I missed the `$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $q);` part. Updated. Cheers.